# How to add lines in this java code?

Tags: java

Hey guys im starting with Java but I'm stuck here. Does anybody know how to add extra lines so the results won't be pasted behind each other?

```
package h2.opdracht.pkg4.vraag;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class H2Opdracht4Vraag {


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int a, b, c, d, e, f;
      System.out.println("Enter three numbers: ");
      Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
       a = in.nextInt();
       b = in.nextInt();
       c = in.nextInt();

       d = a + b + c;

         System.out.print("Sum of the numbers = " + d);

       e = d/3;
         System.out.print("The average of the numbers = " + e);

       f = a * b * c;
         System.out.print("The product of the numbers  = " + f);

       if (a <= b)
           System.out.print("A is the smallest number ");
       else if (b <= c)
           System.out.print("B is the smallest number ");
       else
           System.out.print("C is the smallest number ");
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `System.out.println("Your text here");` instead of print. That adds a line break.

Answer (score 0):

Use `System.out.println` instead of `System.out.print`

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `System.out.print("data");` use `System.out.println("data");`.
`"print();"` does not add a new line after and that's why you get results behind each other while `println();` adds a new line.

For more details on:

1. print: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/PrintStream.html#print-java.lang.String-
2. println: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/PrintStream.html#println--

Comment: It worked! Thank you for the info. Just amazing how fast you'll responded thanks !!